# Pressure in Bernoulli principle

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory

In Bernoulli principle we say that as velocity increases the pressure of fluid decreases but it contradicts kinetic theory of gas which says that as velocity increase-pressure increases. And this seems intuitive also. Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two different 'kinds' of velocity. The one referenced in the Bernoulli principle is a stream velocity, where a fluid moves more or less uniformly in one direction. The velocity referenced in kinetic theory of gases is the *thermal velocity*, which is the average velocity of the random thermal movement of the particles.

Take a gas without flow at a temperature T. The Bernoulli velocity will be zero, but the velocity used in kinetic gas theory will *not* be zero because of the thermal movements of the particles, which are described by the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.